# maven classpath changes between phases

Tags: java, maven

I have a multimodule project. I have some resource files in a dependent project which I load using the class loader.
This works fine in the test part of the life cycle but fails in package due to the classpath being buggered up. Dumping the classpath shows that I have all my dependencies in test but not in package.
Any ideas why my classpath would change between phases?

Comment: what is the dependency scope of dependency which is not available during package phase and which is available during test phase ?

Comment: Default scope - compile.

Comment: and how are you dumping classpath during package phase ?

Comment: I am using debug level logging with the Reflections class.